# jQuery unbind behaviour after function runs

Tags: jquery

I have a toolbar that manipulates a Google map. Some of the functions affect markers placed on the map. I have a reset button that clears the changes and returns the map to the original state.

I need to "disable" the reset button until the map is changed. So...

1. When an action is completed that manipulates the map, I bind the ResetMap() function to the reset button.
2. Reset button is clicked and returns the map to original state.
3. Reset button action is unbound again.

However, I can't get step 3 to work. I tried to unbind the event at the end of the ResetMap() function like so:

```
function ResetMap(){
 var Wrapper = $("#page_layout").find("#InlineToolbarMessages");
 if(Wrapper.hasClass('isExpanded')){
  Wrapper.removeClass('isExpanded');
  Wrapper.addClass('isCollapsed');
 }
 $("#page_layout").find('#NumSelectedNumber').html("0");
 $("#page_layout").find('div#SelectedVoters').html("");
 clearMarkers();
 $('#page_layout').find('#reset_button').unbind('click', function(){
  ResetMap();
 });
}
```

I also tried a more global:

```
$('#page_layout').find('#reset_button').unbind();
```

without success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found out that if I did $('#reset_button').unbind('click'); before I called the ClearMarkers() function that it worked. Similarly in another function for a different button, I put the unbind at the beginning and it worked. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Based on your comment that you *"...found out that if [you] did `$('#reset_button').unbind('click');` before [you] called the `ClearMarkers()`` function that it worked. Similarly in another function for a different button, [you] put the unbind at the beginning and it worked."*:

That makes me think that either A) The code earlier is throwing an exception, preventing your getting to the `unbind` call at all, or B) The code earlier is removing the `reset_button` button *or adding another one with the same ID* (which will make the document invalid and the behavior of an ID selector indeterminate).

---

**Original Answer**

Change

```
$('#page_layout').find('#reset_button').unbind('click', function(){
    ResetMap();
});
```

to

```
$('#page_layout').find('#reset_button').unbind('click', ResetMap);
```

...assuming you used `ResetMap` in the `bind` call. Since you haven't shown the `bind`, it's hard to say for certain.

When you call [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) with a function reference, it has to be the *exact same function reference* that you gave [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (or one of `bind`'s shortcuts, [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and such).

So for instance, this works:

```
// Binding
$("#myElement").bind("click", myFunction);

// Unbinding
$("#myElement").unbind("click", myFunction);
```

...but this **does not work**:

```
// Binding
$("#myElement").bind("click", function() {
    myFunction();
});

// Unbinding
$("#myElement").unbind("click", function() { // <== Does not work
    myFunction();
});
```

...because the function references are not the same.